# Units from non root user (for commands start/stop/enable/disable)

Tags: linux, startup, fedora16, systemd

I want to execute my scripts at boot time through `systemd` (OS is Fedora Core 16) from some non-root user (e.g. `michael`).

I don't need root privileges - I only want to run at boot time and at shutdown time some of my units in `systemd`. And I don't want to turn on a `root` user for this. I only want to use power of `systemd` syntax of units for starting and watching for my process (of course without root access). Is it possible?

I didn't find any help in the documentation. I only found in `systemd(1) -> DIRECTORIES -> "User unit directories"`:

```
$ pkg-config systemd --variable=systemduserunitdir
/usr/lib/systemd/user
```

But the `/usr/lib/systemd/user` is:

> drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root

I cannot imagine how I can use this directory as a non-root user...

Comment: As i understood the "systemduserunitdir" directory has a units for user sessions (ssh / X sessions?). If yes it variable will not help to me :( I want to start/stop/enable/disable services/daemons in systemd without user sessions (at boot time) but as non root user. And i don't want to obtain root access for installing my programs (daemons) if its don't need in root privileges...

Comment: Have you tried asking this on superuser.com, a related website focusing on computer questions more than programming questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a user systemd unit file for 'michael'.

Here's the magic to ensure users systemd process will kick off at boot instead of at login:

```
loginctl enable-linger michael
```

[Full details](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_start-up_of_systemd_user_instances)

Answer (score 3):

[This Arch Linux document may help.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User)

> systemd offers users the ability to run an instance of systemd to
>   manage their session and services. This allows users to start, stop,
>   enable, and disable units found within certain directories when
>   systemd is run by the user. This is convenient for daemons and other
>   services that are commonly run as a user other than root or a special
>   user, such as mpd.

They suggest starting a system --user instance via xinit, but I suppose you want to start the user services regardless of whether the user is logged in.

I would normally do that by adding an @reboot line to my crontab.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#cite_ref-debiancron_2-0):

> @reboot can be useful if there is a need to start up a server or
>   daemon under a particular user, and the user does not have access to
>   configure init to start the program.

Maybe you can start systemd --user via @reboot!!!